# Why my dialogs doesn't work?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dialog that open when the page is reloaded and ask for the login. This was working perfectly until I create another dialog that open when I click in a button. Both have different names and I am calling then right! I really don't know what is wrong..

Now, when I reload the page it shows me the login dialog and I put the right login and password but it rejects.. But if I remove the other dialog and do the same thinh, it works.

My code:

```
<body onload="PF('dlgLogin').show();">
        <h:form name="">
            <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true" life="2000" />

            <p:dialog header="Login" widgetVar="dlgLogin" modal="true" closable="false" resizable="false">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                    <h:outputLabel for="login" value="Username:" />
                    <p:inputText id="login" value="#{loginView.login}" required="true" label="Login" />
                    <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
                    <p:password id="password" value="#{loginView.senha}" required="true" label="Password" />
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton value="Login" update="growl" action="#{loginView.login}"
                                         oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)" />
                    </f:facet> 
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:dialog>

            <p:dialog header="Nova classificação" widgetVar="dlgClassificacao" modal="true" resizable="false">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                    <h:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:" />
                    <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{adminView.classNome}" required="true" label="Nome" />
                    <h:outputLabel for="valor" value="Valor:" />
                    <p:inputText id="valor" value="#{adminView.classPreco}" required="true" label="Valor" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <f:facet name="footerAdicionar">
                    <p:commandButton value="Adicionar" action="#{adminView.novaClassificacao}" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:dialog>

            <p:layout>
                <p:layoutUnit position="center">

                    <p:dataTable id="classificacoes" selection="#{adminView.selectedClassificacao}" var="classificacao" value="#{adminView.classificacoes}" style="margin-bottom:20px">

                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{adminView.onRowSelect}"/>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Nome" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{classificacao.nome}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Valor" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{classificacao.preco}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton title="Novo" icon="ui-icon-document" onclick="PF('dlgClassificacao').show();" type="button"/>
                        <p:commandButton title="Editar" icon="ui-icon-pencil" />
                        <p:commandButton title="Deletar" icon="ui-icon-trash" update="classificacoes" actionListener="#{adminView.excluirClassificacao}"/>
                    </f:facet>

                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>

        </h:form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) {
                if(args.validationFailed || !args.loggedIn) {
                    PF('dlg').jq.effect("shake", {times:5}, 100);
                }
                else {
                    PF('dlg').hide();
                    $('#loginLink').fadeOut();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Any errors in console? `F12`

Comment: @Geinmachi: it's just the God Form antipattern. Gustavo, pay closer attention to field names in validation error messages.

Comment: No errors. @Geinmachi

Comment: @BalusC I am not getting errors, and if I remove my second dialog, it will work fine!

Comment: Then try to remove things IN the second dialog. And once pinpointed, remove attributes on what you found. That is debugging

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sending all the form data when you press the login button. Then you obtain messages indicating that you have not (naturally) typed any data for `Nome` nor `Valor` fields.

You can fix it by adding an id attribute to your login dialog and to your form and also adding a process attribute to your login button:

```
<p:commandButton process=":yourForm:dlgLogin" value="Login" 
    update="growl" action="#{loginView.login}" />
```